Resids vs fitted plot shows cyclical patterns. I have chosen 5 explanatory variables out of 300. Should I add more or do I risk overfitting?
I'm predicting the relative abundance of 1 genus (y) based on the relative abundance of other genus (the variables are each genus name). I have arbitrarily chosen the 5 genus that seemed the most likely to help (the 5 most abundant genus through time for all my replicates), but I have a total of more than 300 genus in my community. I predicted the abundance of 2 bacterial genus and 2 eukaryotic genus using the same methodology.
I'm writing an article and am thinking of saying that, while the diagnostic plots aren't that great and that the addition of other genus could most likely help the predictions, the inclusion of only these 5 genus  enables us to predict fairly accurately the changes through time.
That modelisation is not the core of my article and does not aim at predicting a phenomenon taking place in the real world, but is more of an exploratory process to simply see IF the variation in relative abundance of genera could be predicted. Would that line of thought hold in a published article?
Here is the model I used:
mod_och <- mvgam(y ~ s(time, by = Apoikiaceae) + 
                   s(time, by = Unclassified_Eukaryota) +
                   s(time, by = Sessilida) +
                   s(time, by = Sandonidae) +
                   s(Others) +
                   s(bioreactor, bs = 're'),
                 data = data_train,
                 newdata = data_test,
                 share_obs_params = TRUE,
                 family = betar(link = 'logit'),
                 trend_model = AR(1),
                 noncentred = TRUE,
                 parallel = TRUE,
                 chains = 4,
                 backend = 'cmdstanr')

I have 51 datapoints of training and 17 for testing so I'm fairly restricted on the data. As it's an exploratory model, I've contructed it based on previous testing and the theory.
Here is the resids vs fitted and qqplot of the model (obtained using 'plot(mod_och, type = 'residuals', series = 3)', the tails are heavy and residuals not normally distributed

I assumed the red line had to be straight, but based on @EdM 's comment, it seems that as long as the residuals are distributed around 0 randomly (which is not the case here), I can ignore the red line?
I cannot figure out how to remove the red line, but since we can see the points aswell, would that be fine?
Here is the forecast. I used 70% for training and 30% for testing

The modelling is done in R using the package mvgam

What does your model look like? How many observations do you have? How did you assess predictive performance?

Please edit the question to say more about your measure of "relative abundance" and how that corresponds to the "DS residuals" scale of your plot. It's not clear how significant those residuals might be in practice. Also, consider removing the smooth curve from the residuals versus fitted plot. That might be leading you astray, given what seem to be big gaps among the fitted values that the single curve has to try to bridge.

These randomised quantile residuals can often show spurious patterns with a beta regression (it is difficult to estimate the shape parameter that controls dispersion when modelling proportional data), so I wouldn't worry too much about over interpretation of these diagnostics in particular. But it is worth looking at other forms of model fit, such as posterior predictive checks using pp_check(). You will also want to explore inferences for your smooth terms using plot_predictions(). Lastly, your forecasts are certainly leveraging the linear predictor information because an AR(1) process on its own cannot behave in that way(i.e. by oscillating). This suggests the model might be useful, but if you'd like to understand what added value these other genera provide for explaining the observations, you could build a reduced model that excludes those terms and use either out of sample forecast comparisons or approximate forecast comparisons (i.e. with lfo_cv()).


That modelisation is not the core of my article and does not aim at predicting a phenomenon taking place in the real world, but is more of an exploratory process to simply see IF the variation in relative abundance of genera could be predicted. Would that line of thought hold in a published article?

The answer probably depends more on what's expected in your field of study than on statistical analysis per se. That said, if you are going to report a model then it should meet some basic quality control metrics. Yours doesn't seem to.
Primarily, as you acknowledge, there seems to be a very large increase in residuals around fitted values as the fitted values increase. (I don't think that any underlying "cyclical" patterns are much to worry about, as they are probably more a function of the smoothing function rather than the data. The trend, however, is troubling.) That's certainly not what you would want with a linear least squares model, and I don't think it's a good sign for a beta-regression model like yours, either. I also suspect that the normal q-q plot isn't useful with beta regression. I'm not even sure that beta regression is a good choice in this situation if the total abundance varies substantially among observations (as it might if these are observations over time during culture in a bioreactor).
I don't know much about beta regression. You might look at this web page and its links for guidance. An author of the package used on that page has many answers on this site related to beta regression. This answer might have some more helpful references.
Second, I don't find your forecast example to be very convincing. The values during the forecast period are very close to constant, perhaps continuing a  slight downward trend that starts at about Time = 12 after a couple of early oscillations. Your model doesn't seem to add much that couldn't be handled with a simple extrapolation, at least at those late time points.
Third, I'm not at all an expert with your type of data. Discuss with colleagues in your field whether this might nevertheless be of interest.
